# Sharepoint 2010 Excel - Extra fields in export xls

Tags: list, sharepoint-designer, list-view, export

I have a view of about 80 fields (base from a list of about 200 fields) that I want to export into excel but the export shows up with extra fields (fields that are being used in some of the calculated fields in the view). Is there any way to not export the extra fields? I know the Item Type and Path fields are exported by default, is there a way to not export them also?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately no.  SharePoint will export the fields from your view as well as the default extra fields and any calculated fields used by the columns in your view.

Comment: Can we have a source for the last answer? Because I had the same question and I don't want to search for nothing.